# creating connection string for attached MDF file

Tags: c#, database, wpf, backup, mdf

what you see bellow is a part of my WPF project I used it to backup/restore my SQL server database and it works great but; when I want to make a setup file by advanced installer and I move MDF and LDF files created by SQL script to app directory to use in SQL express it doesn't work. Now I want to know what can I do with connection string so that backup/restore prosses can work correctly

```
 private string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\\DBNBO.mdf;Database=DBNBO; Trusted_Connection=Yes;";

  private void BtnBackup_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            string database = connection.Database;
                                 string query = "Backup Database [" + database + "] To Disk = '" + txtBackup.Text + "\\DB_backup.bak'";
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();          
                    connection.Close();
         }


private void btnRestore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            string database = connection.Database;
                    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) connection.Open();
                    string query1 = string.Format("Alter Database [" + database + "] Set Single_User With Rollback Immediate");
                    SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(query1, connection);
                    command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    string query2 = string.Format("Use Master Restore Database [" + database + "] From Disk = '" + txtRestore.Text + "' With Replace");
                    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(query2, connection);
                    command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    string query3 = string.Format("Alter Database [" + database + "] Set Multi_User");
                    SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand(query3, connection);
                    command3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: there is no solution for my question!!!???

Comment: We guess which line produces the error?

Comment: Is there nobody help me, please?

Comment: How can I use My app on client computer without installing SSMS just with SQL express?